# Getting Seek events from the YouTube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am embedding a YouTube video on my page and am able to detect when the user clicks Play and Pause on the video.

I need to also be able to detect when the user does a seek / jumps to  a particular part of the video (as opposed to letting it just play to that point). How do I do this?

I am using the Youtube iframe api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I am able to hack around this by starting a timer and checking every second if the video played by more than a second and if so considering it as a seek. However, it seems that there should be an easier way of doing this.

Comment: @Tyler - My solution was to use the hack that I mentioned above. It worked well.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was hoping it wouldn't come to that. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: Not a problem. Best of luck with it.